# How to Return a DOPL within a Function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I think I've nearly got it but not quite, I'm trying to return a DOPL value within my function but can't figure out the problem (thanks in advance).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_CUST_STRING_FROM_DB (pcustid NUMBER) RETURN 
VARCHAR2 AS
vCustname VARCHAR2(100);
vStatus VARCHAR2(7);
vSalesYTD NUMBER;
vStr VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN 
SELECT CUSTNAME, SALES_YTD, STATUS INTO vCustname, vStatus, vSalesYTD FROM 
Customer
WHERE pcustid = CUSTID;
vStr := DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Custid: ' || pcustid || ' Name: ' || vCustname 
|| ' Status: ' || vStatus || ' SalesYTD: ' || vSalesYTD);
RETURN vStr;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20021, 'Customer ID not found');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, SQLERRM);
END;
 /
```

Comment: fyi ppl - The SELECT is in the wrong order, need to change the vStatus & vSalesYTD around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace below mentioned line to

```
vStr := 'Custid: ' || pcustid || ' Name: ' || vCustname 
|| ' Status: ' || vStatus || ' SalesYTD: ' || vSalesYTD;
```